# Dismiss Keyboard in one of multiple views

Tags: ios, objective-c, keyboard

I have a 3 views in one screen with different components such as tables and buttons, when I try to dismiss the keyboard with the code below it doesn't dismiss when I click on the view that contains the textView( and that’s what I need! ) . However when I click on one of the other views it dismisses.

The following image shows the views that I have and the last view inside the scrollview is the one that contains the textView.

[image]

How can I get the keyboard to dismiss despite the view that is taped.

```
-(void)touchesBegan:(NSSet *)touches withEvent:(UIEvent *)event {

UITouch * touch = [touches anyObject];

if(touch.phase == UITouchPhaseBegan) {
    [aTextField resignFirstResponder];
  }
}
```

also this code fails to dismiss:

```
- (void)touchesBegan:(NSSet *)touches withEvent:(UIEvent *)event {

[[self view] endEditing:TRUE];

}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to add tap gesture in the views which you want to click:
For you are using two UIViews with name Your_view1 and Your_view2, and textfields are txt1 and txt2. The code is below:

Your_view1:

```
UITapGestureRecognizer *singleTapGesture = [[UITapGestureRecognizer alloc] initWithTarget:self action:@selector(handleSingleTapGesture:)];
singleTapGesture.numberOfTapsRequired = 1;
[Your_view1 addGestureRecognizer:singleTapGesture];
```

Your_view2:

```
UITapGestureRecognizer *singleTapGesture = [[UITapGestureRecognizer alloc] initWithTarget:self action:@selector(handleSingleTapGesture:)];
singleTapGesture.numberOfTapsRequired = 1;
[Your_view2 addGestureRecognizer:singleTapGesture];
```

And the delegate is:

```
-(void)handleSingleTapGesture:(UITapGestureRecognizer *)singleTapGesture{
    [txt1 resignFirstResponder];
    [txt2 resignFirstResponder];
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If your textView is editable , tapping on that, will make it first responder. That’s why keyboard is not dismissing. If you don’t need edit textView, set it’s editable attribute to false

Comment: Thank you for your answer however I want the textView to be editable.

Comment: @DvixExtract ammm I don’t get it. User taps on textView, so he wants to edit it. But you want to hide keyboard. What?

Comment: so the user clicks on the textview and they enter text, afterwards they should tap anywhere on the screen so that the keyboard dismisses.

Comment: @DvixExtract you said I works now. From your question: “ however when I tap other views it dismisses”

Comment: see I have 3 views as shown in the image. When I tap on one of the views which doesn't contain the textView it dismisses the keyboard. What I want is to tap on the view that contains the textView so that it dismisses the keyboard.

Comment: @DvixExtract check your textViews constraint. If it’s frame size is equal to your views size, textField will get firstResponder and keyboard won’t hide

Comment: they are not equal

Answer (score 0):

You should take a look at Apple document for [UIScrollView](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uiscrollview#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40006922).

> Because a scroll view has no scroll bars, it must know whether a touch signals an intent to scroll versus an intent to track a subview in the content. To make this determination, **it temporarily intercepts a touch-down event by starting a timer** and, before the timer fires, seeing if the touching finger makes any movement.

That's why `touchesBegan` doesn't work when you click inside your scroll view.

A easy way to fix it, add a `UITapGestureRecognizer` for your `viewController.view`.

```
@property (nonatomic, strong) UITapGestureRecognizer *tapGestureRecognizer;

- (void)viewDidLoad {
  [super viewDidLoad];
  self.tapGestureRecognizer = [[UITapGestureRecognizer alloc] initWithTarget:self.aTextField action:@selector(resignFirstResponder)];
  [self.view addGestureRecognizer:self.tapGestureRecognizer];
}
```

Answer (score 0):

managing keyboard get most of our development time luckly we have an alternative solution with this [library](https://github.com/hackiftekhar/IQKeyboardManager)

No need to write multiple line of code in every viewcontroller simply add one line of code in your `didFinishLaunchingWithOptions`

```
IQKeyboardManager.sharedManager().enable = true
```

This will save time 
Hope this will help you